# Where there are attempts to enter a password for unlocking operator sim lock?

Tags: sim-unlocking, telephony

My phone (Micromax Q415) attached to the SIM card operator megaphone. If I insert a SIM card of another operator, the phone will ask for the unlock key. I found an application that shows this screen and decompiling it. I want to modify this application so that it performs a brute force attack locally. Each entry attempt occurs with a fake delay, which I already lost. Now you need to know where are the attempts to enter the NCK password. I tried to backup the entire system, spent one try, performed a backup restore. But the attemts can not be restored! Where are these attempts? In the course of this application I saw that the number of attempts is taken from the telephony-common.jar. But I did not find where this request goes.

Comment: Just a guess -  there's more partitions than what you touch with a file manager. If it's in modem (firmware) or EFS then you're pretty much screwed - and I don't see why they wouldn't do so.

Comment: @Andy Yan, very interesting :) The number of attempts can be in the "dev" directory?

Comment: I very much doubt that, Sergej. `/dev` is using the devfs file system and is not permanent, but "re-created" at each boot.